# String doesn't "rewind" itself when accessing via pointer

Tags: c, substring, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings, function-definition

```
char *ft_between(char *str, size_t from, size_t to)
{
    char *between;

    between = malloc(16);

    while ((from >= 0) && (from < to) && (to < ft_strlen(str)))
    {
        *(between++) = str[from++];
    }
    *between = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", between); // print nothing
    printf("%s\n", between - 16); // print between but never had to do this before...
    return (between);// even on calling function the pointer still at end of string
}
```

I think it's because I changed the address of between using ++ but I usually do that and never had this behavior... is that because of malloc ???

Is there someting I missed ?
Is thear a way to "rewind" the string lol
If I do it via a counter ie. between[counter++] = str[from++]; it works but I wanted to do via pointers as it's faster... from what I've red !

In this example str is iterate with ++ until the end to add char
but when return in calling function a printf will print all str

```
void    ft_nbr2str(char *str, size_t nbr, char *base, size_t base_len)
{
    if (nbr >= base_len)
    {
        ft_nbr2str(str, (nbr / base_len), base, base_len);
        while (*str != '\0')
            str++;
        *str = base[nbr % base_len];
    }
    else
        *str = base[nbr];
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show an example of code that worked as you expected after incrementing the pointer.  The code you've shown so far works exactly the way I'd expect.

Comment: Why are you calling `strlen` *every single time* through the loop?  For that matter, `(to < ft_strlen(str))` should be loop-invariant, so why is it part of the `while` test?

Comment: If you're changing `between`, then it will no longer point to the beginning of your string.  Save the original value, then use that to examine (and return) the result.

Comment: I would _not_ hardwire the `malloc` arg as 16. How did you get that? You had to run this by hand to figure that out. I'd use `realloc` in the loop so you have exact control and don't have to "divine" the value of 16.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After this statement

```
*between = '\0';
```

the pointer `between` points to an empty string. So this call of `printf`:

```
printf("%s\n", between); // print nothing
```

indeed will output nothing.

And this return statement

```
return (between);// even on calling function the pointer still at end of string
```

returns this pointer to an empty string.

Pay attention to that this condition

```
(from >=0)
```

does not make sense because objects of the unsigned type `size_t` can not be negative.

Also it is unclear why there is used the magic number `16`

```
between = malloc(16);
```

and

```
printf("%s\n", between - 16); // print between but never had to do this before...
```

And the function should not output any message. It is the caller of the function that will decide whether to output something.

The function can be declared and defined the following way

```
char * ft_between( const char *str, size_t from, size_t to )
{
    char *between;

    size_t n = ft_strlen( str );

    if ( n < to ) to = n;

    if ( to <= from )
    {
        between = calloc( 1, sizeof( char ) );
    }
    else
    {  
        between = malloc( to - from + 1 );
        if ( between != NULL )
        {
            char *p = between;
            while ( from != to ) *p++ = str[from++];
            *p = '\0';
        }
    }

    return between;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I think it's because I changed the address of between using ++

It's because you modified the *value* of `between` via the `++` operator.  That value is the address of something else.  The *address* of `between` or any other object cannot be modified.

> but I usually do that and never had this behavior.

The behavior you describe is absolutely normal, so either no, you *don't* usually do that, or yes you did have that behavior.  In your code, you will observe the same effect on `from`.  I really don't fathom why immediately after you execute `*between = '\0';` you would expect `printf("%s\n", between)` to print a non-empty string.  `malloc` has nothing in particular to do with it.

I speculate that in other cases you may have instead modified *a copy* of your pointer, which, naturally, does not modify the original pointer.  Possibly you did this by passing your pointer (by value) to another function.  Example:

```
void strcpy_range(char *dest, char *src, size_t from, size_t to) {
    while ((from >=0) && (from < to) && (src[from] != '\0'))
    {
        *(dest++) = src[from++];  // dest is modified
    }
    *dest = '\0';
}

char    *ft_between(char *str, size_t from, size_t to)
{
    char *between = malloc(16);

    strcpy_range(between, str, from, to);

    printf("%s\n", between); // prints the extracted substring
    return between;          // returns a pointer to the extracted substring
}
```

If you want to rescue your original version without introducing a new function, then use a temporary variable to track the current location in the substring.  For example,

```
char    *ft_between(char *str, size_t from, size_t to)
{
    char *between = malloc(16);
    char *temp = between;
    while ((from >=0) && (from < to) && (to < ft_strlen(str)))
    {
        *(temp++) = str[from++];
    }
    *temp = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", between); // prints the extracted substring
    return between;          // returns the extracted substring
}
```

### Addendum

The alternative example added to the question demonstrates exactly the form I speculated you might have used.  The (non-)effect on the caller's copy of the pointer in that case is not analogous to or even related to the modification of the function parameter observed during execution of the first function presented in the question.

Comment: There are other issues with the original code, some of which are highlighted by differences between the two alternatives presented here.  For the most part, however, this answer focuses on the question actually posed.

Comment: how to close question as vlad answer satisfy me !!

Comment: @RoGKôT You can for example select my answer as the best answer.

Comment: I had accept your answer and also another one but this is not closing the question

Comment: @RoGKôT: Stack Overflow leaves good questions open to help other people with similar questions in the future. Bad or inappropriate questions are closed (and may be deleted).

Answer (score 0):

After you've incremented the pointer, it now points to a different region of memory. Since the pointer is of type char, summing one unit is the same as summing sizeof(char) units, which turns out to still be 1; to 'rewind' it, as you say, you'd just have to subtract 16 * sizeof(char) = 16 (notice you're dereferencing the pointer summed by 16, so it makes perfect sense to subtract 16 to get it back to its position, or subtract however many times you want so that it points to the location you expect it to)

Comment: How do you know it's 16? Or _any_ length? To do so, we'd need: `char *orig = between;` before the loop [or a loop counter of some sort]. Then, after `between -= between - orig;` But, easier to just do: `between = orig;` or `printf("%s",orig);` after the loop; Here "rewind" might be better expressed as "return/reset to original".

Comment: I have simplify the code because it was not working so using 16 is just for test purpose... so basically the answer from vlad is pretty cool. I will use it...

Comment: thanks to everybody !! it is very cool to have help from experienced coders...